From which time a window is calculated in apache-beam?
I am writing a beam streaming pipeline, with 1 min Fixed Window.
I am reading data from PubSub, and using PubSub msg's Timestamp:
beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(60)))
As, PubSub msg already have Timestamp information, I am not giving Timestamp info explicitly.
Now, my question is:

Suppose I start my beam pipeline at "2019-03-27T09:50:00.000Z" and I start publishing to PubSub      Topic at 2019-03-27T09:50:20.000Z,  from which time the pipeline will start counting 1min? What will be window start and end time.

Second question, What If published msgs are out of order. I mean, suppose I published one msg at *2019-03-27T09:50:10.000Z *and another at 2019-03-27T09:50:40.000Z, but 2019-03-27T09:50:40.000Z arrives first and consumed by beam. So ,in this case, what will be start time of Window.


Thanks for the help in advance.
I have created streaming pipeline, and want to know, about window start time. Which time it consider as start of window.

By default, beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(60)) will use the event time (Pub/Sub message timestamp) to assign elements to windows.
Use allowed_lateness to allow the late data.
Please check this:
https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#watermarks-and-late-data

The way to think about Windowing is that it divides the entire timeline up into a set of windows, e.g.
...
[2019-03-27T09:50:00.000Z, 2019-03-27T09:51:00.000Z)
[2019-03-27T09:51:00.000Z, 2019-03-27T09:52:00.000Z)
[2019-03-27T09:52:00.000Z, 2019-03-27T09:53:00.000Z)
[2019-03-27T09:53:00.000Z, 2019-03-27T09:54:00.000Z)
...

and then as elements come in it assigns each one to one of the windows based on its timestamp (regardless of when the pipeline started). By default these are aligned with the beginning of the epoc, but FixedWindows does take an offset parameter if this is not desired, e.g. `FixedWindows(60, offset=15) would chop the timeline into windows
...
[2019-03-27T09:50:15.000Z, 2019-03-27T09:51:15.000Z)
[2019-03-27T09:51:15.000Z, 2019-03-27T09:52:15.000Z)
[2019-03-27T09:52:15.000Z, 2019-03-27T09:53:15.000Z)
[2019-03-27T09:53:15.000Z, 2019-03-27T09:54:15.000Z)
...

It also does not matter which elements come "first." Each elements of a window are held up in any grouping/aggregating operation until all the elements arrive. (There are some subtleties here, as we rely on the source, such as PubSub, to tell us at which point all elements up to timestamp X have been delivered (and if it's wrong, this would be considered "late data," and one can influence the emission of elements based on triggers as well, but most pipelines need not concern themselves with those difficulties.)
